# Include history of economics, plain economic facts

Tags: discussion

I think it would be useful to extend the scope of the site to questions about certain economic facts.
For example I would like to ask questions like "Where can I find international trade relations statistics, by year?" where answers like "For Germany-France trade statistics, check link1, link2 and link3" can be valid. Of course an answer pointing to a few sources documenting all trade relations between all countries will be the best and preferred answer, but that's very unlikely to exist, so specific answers about a country pair are good enough.

Many times such questions cross my mind like "What are the largest agricultural companies in the US?", "Where can I find a list with the price of land in the US, by year?" and so on.

I think such questions are quite interesting, they are about economy, although more about economic numbers and history than about economy theories and concepts. In my view there is no reason to try to create a separate SO site about economic history, and it would be nice if such questions could fit here.

Later edit: another example question: "What's the most important imports for UK? (raw materials and products that the country doesn't have (enough) and can't produce, like for example soy, banana, watermelons, etc.)"

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be close to requesting Data Sets, which it is, at least for the moment, considered in principle on-topic in the main site (See the relevant meta-post [Should we allow questions about obtaining particular datasets?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/105/61))

Nevertheless, I have to point out that for data requests, the "be narrow and specific" seems to reverse as guidance: it should be "Where can I find data on UK imports?" rather than "what are the most imiportant UK imports" (but maybe that's marginal).